# Maximum limit of Linkedlist

Tags: c, memory-management, linked-list, operating-system

I am new in CS world.While reading some books i checked that dynamic allocation of memory, allocates memory dynamically while program runs and that memory is called heap.So that means whenever i want to create a new node in Linkedlist it get stored on heap? or else it get stored on memory and accessed runtime?

And i also checked that whenever any programs ran, the OS creates PCB for the same including minimum 4 following parts:

1. Heap Segment
2. Stack segment
3. Data segment
4. Code segment

And heap segment and stack segment grows dynamically depends on code(upwards or downwards depends on system).

So my basic question is

> The maximum element we can add in Linkedlist until system memory exhausts or heap memory exhausts?

I read that its until system memory exhausts.But i wondered how?

Comment: maximum virtual memory provided by OS..

Comment: virtual memory? can you explain?

Comment: It is hard to come up with a precise number. First a program obtains memory from the OS (in pages or by growing a segment); the available size depends on many factors, including the amount of physical RAM and the current memory consumption by other programs. Second in this memory not only list nodes will be allocated but also various bookkeeping data used by the heap implementation.

Comment: For most operating systems, the stack segment is allocated at process load time or thread creation time, and doesn't grow dynamically.

Comment: @rcgldr, can you give example for the same?

Comment: Generally, there's a compiler option to set the stack size for a process. For Windows, CreateThread() includes a parameter to set the stack size for a thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best explanation I've read yet:

> Because the heap grows up and the stack grows down, they basically limit each other. Also, because both type of segments are writeable, it wasn't always a violation for one of them to cross the boundary, so you could have buffer or stack overflow. Now there are mechanism to stop them from happening.
>
> There is a set limit for heap (stack) for each process to start with. This limit can be changed at runtime (using brk()/sbrk()). Basically what happens is when the process needs more heap space and it has run out of allocated space, the standard library will issue the call to the OS. The OS will allocate a page, which usually will be manage by user library for the program to use. I.e. if the program wants 1 KiB, the OS will give additional 4 KiB and the library will give 1 KiB to the program and have 3 KiB left for use when the program ask for more next time.

Excerpt from [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/207400/55950).

Comment: You mean heap can request dynamically a new page whenever it's size get full.So probably the answer will be till system memory or virtual memory as said by "Shan" exhausts,right?

Comment: Indeed. That's the short answer. But it's also good to know how the mechanism works.

Answer (score 0):

If you dynamically allocate memory you get it from the heap.

From the statement above you can directly conclude that if you allocate a list's nodes dynamically, the maximum numbers of nodes is limited by the heap's size, that is by the amount of heap-memory.

Comment: That means i can add as many as element that OS gives memory for the process?(as it depends on heap)

Comment: "*as many as element that OS gives memory for the process*" devided by the size of the node, yes ... - theoratically. Keep in mind that the stack also need memory, and that memory fragmentation might lead to nasty side effects ... @Avinash